# Does Hall conductivity change sign with chemical potential?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electrical-resistance, topological-insulators, quantum-hall-effect

The transverse conductivity $\sigma_{xy}$ at zero frequency is quantized when the chemical potential $\mu$ is within the gap for a topological system. A typical plot of $\sigma_{xy}(\mu)$ is like the following. Another closely related quantity is the (optical) Hall conductivity $\sigma_H(\omega)=[\sigma_{xy}(\omega)-\sigma_{yx}(\omega)]/2$ for general $\omega$. In many cases, e.g., systems with $C_4$ rotation symmetry, we have $\sigma_H=\sigma_{xy}$. Let's ignore the difference here.

[image]

It is known that $\mathrm{Re}\,\sigma_H(\omega,\mu)$ for general $\omega$ will ***change sign*** at some $\mu$, where *the type of main carrier changes from electron to hole or the like*. An example is the following plot (solid line for real part) at some fixed $\omega$ from this [PRL paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4471). It uses the Kubo formula for a particle-hole symmetric BdG system.

[image]

My question:

Does the sign change argument always hold at any frequency? I naively think so. It is used in experiments to determine carrier type, probably very often in dc transport. If it holds also for $\omega=0$, the first figure with quantized result seems to be contradictory?

Comment: Related (also unanswered) [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/535942/is-there-an-ac-version-of-the-quantum-hall-effect)